# How to link to page other than index.php on my website (all other pages result in error)?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

It seems absurdly basic, but I keep getting errors linking to any page other than index.php from within my site. For example,

```
<p>No thanks, return to the <a href="index.php">home page</a>.</p>
```

works perfectly fine and loads the `http://example.com/index.php` page when clicked. However, both

```
<p>No thanks, return to the <a href="thankyou.php">home page</a>.</p>
```

and

```
<p>No thanks, return to the <a href="http://example.com/thankyou.php">home page</a>.</p>
```

result in an error* when clicked, even though I can go enter the address `http://example.com/thankyou.php` directly in a browser address bar and it loads perfectly.

*The error message is:

```
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID), timestamp int NOT NU' at line 1
```

Comment: Another example on a different page of the same site is `// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
}
?>` If I change `index.php` to `thankyou.php` there's an error (sigh)

Comment: Are you running any MySQL query in your script thankyou.php?

Answer (score 1):

You should check that you are not creating a table in your thankyou.php script or in any script that thankyou.php includes or requires.

Comment: Okay, @Diamond, I removed `<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');
require_once('process.php');
?>`

from top of thankyou.php and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

However, what if I (or another person in the Stack community) is linking to a page where these exist (and load and work perfectly if typed directly into a browser address bar)? Any suggestion on how to make that work?

Comment: Check that the link and type address are actually the same, if so, clear your browser cache and also check if no script is called on the current page while the link is being loaded. Another thing is to check .htaccess file configuration. Read .htaccess tips and tricks here http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: The hyperlink and URL typed in the browser address bar are identical.

Comment: When using the link, and the destination is a PHP page that begins `<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');
require_once('process.php');
?>`, I still get the error `Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID), timestamp int NOT NU' at line 1` I don't understand why the error only appears via the link (typing the destination directly into the address bar causes the page to load perfectly and error-free).

Comment: Also @Diamond, even after reviewing the `corz.org...` page you suggest above, I have no idea what I'd be checking .htaccess for. Would you explain what problem I should be looking to uncover?

Comment: There should be an error log created in the same directory as thankyou.php can you share that please.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to get it, but GoDaddy's cPanel hosting has it hidden, so I need to work through that. Best, -MG

Comment: It's not hidden, just haven't been created...you have to create it yourself... Add a new file inside your public_html folder and name it ".htaccess". Right click and edit, then add all your Apache configuration code there. Note that this .htaccess file will have effect on all subfolders. If there's any folder you don't want it to affect, create a new empty one in the folder and the folder will be bypassed.